# Mutable and immutable objects show different behviours in functions wit python

Tags: python

Why mutable objects like array or list can be visited and changed in function directly while immutable objects like number can be only visited but not changed? What is the mechnism. Below is some simple test code.

```
import numpy as np

a = [1,2,3]
b = np.array([1,2,3])
c = 3
def func():
    a.append(1)
    b[0] = 2
    c += 1
    print(c)
    
func()
```

Comment: Please [do not post code as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Show code and other textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as image or external link.

Comment: I don't understand the question. This code prints `4` so clearly `c` was changed. (Of course you cannot change the number 3 _itself_ but you can change variables containing that value.)

Comment: You seem to be asking why mutable objects are mutable but immutable objects are not mutable...

Comment: Thank you! .Since It's my first question, I am not familiar enough with the process.

Comment: Are you asking :  why do I need to specify global for c but not for a and b ?

Answer (score 2):

The difference is whether you *assign* or *mutate*. When you *mutate* data, like with `a.append(1)`, the object reference (`a`) is not changed: it is still the same list reference. When you *assign*, the variable really gets a different reference, and the object that was previously referenced does not get affected.

Without `global`, globals can be mutated (when they are mutable), but not assigned.

This has little to do with mutable or not, as even `a = []` would not be allowed without the corresponding `global` statement. Even though lists are mutable, this `a = []` is not attempting to mutate anything. It assigns. And that requires `global`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're kind of answering your own question.

Mutable objects are *internally* mutable, while immutable objects, well, aren't.

The `global c` (or `nonlocal c` in an inner function) statement tells Python that the name `c` refers to the name `c` in the global (or outer) scope.

Since integers aren't internally mutable (and don't implement `__iadd__`, the magic method that could back `+=`), `c += 1` does `c = c + 1`, i.e. assigns the value of the expression `c + 1` to the global name `c`.

If you attempt `c += 1` in a function without the `global` statement, you'll get an `UnboundLocalError`, since there is no name `c` to access and increment before that assignment itself.

This stands for any name; trying to do

```
>>> a = []
>>> def f():
...     a = a + ["foo"]
...
>>> f()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in f
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment
```

also fails, since `a` has not been assigned within the function.

Comment: Sorry，I have removed the global tag with c in my code. Why c can not be changed with global or nonlocal but mutable obejects can? Thank you, I'm a new hand in python.

Comment: By removing `global c` from your original question, you've made it an entirely different question, and you'll find it doesn't work anymore. The reasons why are outlined in this answer.